# How can i solve my tween strange behaviour in the game?

Tags: phaser-framework

This is the code i am using to create tween in my game, instead out displaying elastic property the tween is displaying a lot of similar sprite stacked on one another, how can i solve this?

```
popup = this.game.add.sprite(this.game.world.centerX, this.game.world.centerY, 'gover');
            popup.anchor.set(0.5);
            popup.inputEnabled = true;
            popup.input.enableDrag();
            popup.scale.set(0);
ctween = this.game.add.tween(popup.scale).to({ x: 1, y: 1 }, 1000, Phaser.Easing.Elastic.Out, true);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The code you shared is fine, but it's probably called more than once. Check whether it is called from an update() function or something.

Comment: yes it's called from an update function, do u think it is the reason for such behaviour ?

Comment: Yes, if it's called several times it's expected that several popups will be created.

Comment: Calling `tween.start()` or a tween starting with the autostart parameter set to `true` should only be done once. Once you start a tween with duration, easing and so on, it will manage itself and you need not to worry any more.